# Detect whether HTML5 History supported or not

Tags: html, pushstate, html5-history

How can I check if the browser you are using supports the HTML5 history api?

As you can see here http://caniuse.com/#search=history only chrome +ff4 and several others supports this and I wish to do something else if they cant support this.

How can I make some kind of an if statement for this checking?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState)
```

See also this [All-In-One Almost-Alphabetical No-Bullshit Guide to Detecting Everything](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html)

Answer (score 24):

You can [detect support](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#historymanagement) for history management (as well as many other browser features) using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

```
if (Modernizr.history)
```

Comment: Modernizr also adds `history` class to your root `html` tag and `no-history` if you don't. That's probably not particularly useful like other features such as `flexbox` but it would allow you to change css depending upon this feature if you really had a need for it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [canisuse.js](https://github.com/btomashvili/caniuse) script to detect if your browsers supports history or not

```
caniuse.history()
```